# Polymer nested dom-repeat templates are not updating when adding items to sub array

Tags: polymer

## Context

I am making a page that displays a list of items. The page lists the items newest to oldest, and categorizes them first by year then by month. It would look something like the following example:

#### 2019

**March**

- list item
- list item 2

**February**

- list item 3

#### 2018

**October**

- list item 4
- list item 5
- list item 6

**May**

- list item 7

A simplified version of the HTML is:

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{years}}" as="year">
    <span>[[year.name]]</span>
    <div id="same-year-items>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{year.months}}" as="month">
            <span>[[month.name]]</span>
            <div id="same-month-items">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{month.items}}" as="item">
                    <custom-list-item item="{{item}}"></custom-list-item>
                </template>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

In the Javascript file I define a `years` array property. Each year in `years` contains a `months` array, and each month in `months` contains an `items` array (see the dom-repeat elements). I query a database for some list items, loop through each item, and then add it to the corresponding month array.

## The issue

This page only loads the first n items. I want to have a "load more" button at the bottom which loads the next n items. (Yes, I know. Infinite scrolling is probably better--that will come later. Even if I were to use infinite scrolling I would still have the issue I'm about to describe.)

When I load more items, the page doesn't update to show the new items. I know Polymer is very particular about how you bind data, especially when it involves sub properties. This is a simplified version of the Javascript which deals with setting the new items to the arrays:

```js
setItems: function(newItems) {
  var tempYearsArray = [];
  for (var i = 0, i < this.years.length; i++) {
    tempYearsArray.push(this.years[i]);
  }
  
  this.set('years', []);
  
  for (var j = 0; j < newItems.length; j++) {
    var item = newItems[j];
    this.setMonthAndYear(item, tempYearsArray);
  }
  
  this.set('years', tempYearsArray);
}

setMonthAndYear: function(item, tempYearsArray) {
  var itemDate = new Date(item.lastModified);
  var currentYear = itemDate.getFullYear();
  var monthIndex = itemDate.getMonth();
  var monthName = this.monthNames[monthIndex];
  var newYear = true;
  var newMonth = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < tempYearsArray.length; i++) {
    var year = tempYearsArray[i];
    if (currentYear === year.name) {
      newYear = false;
      for (j = 0, j < year.months.length; j++) {
        var month = ref[j];
        if (monthName === month.name) {
          month.items.push(item);
          newMonth = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (newMonth) {
        var month = {
          items: [item],
          name: monthName
        };
        year.months.push(month);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  if (newYear) {
    var month = {
      items: [item],
      name: monthName
    };
    year = {
      name: currentYear,
      months: [month]
    };
    return tempYearsArray.push(year);
  }
}
```

I can see that `years` has the new items, but the page still doesn't render them. I've read other posts with similar problems, which is where I got the idea of `this.set('years', [])` and the temporary array. I've also tried doing stuff like `this.notifyPath('year.months', year.months.slice())` and `this.notifyPath('month.items', month.items.slice())`. I'm not sure why this would work, but I saw that suggested in [this Github issues post](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2068).

Also if you have a better suggestion than a years array which contains a months array which contains the item array, all the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you're changing the existing array, which means that Polymer doesn't see any difference between your "changed" array and the previous one ... because they are both the same array (array references, yay!).

You need to either 1) create a new array and let it replace the new one with `this.set()`, 2) clone the array – through `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)` – that you modified and `this.set()` it, 3) Use `this.splice()` because that should, in theory, work, or 4) do what you did: reset the array with an empty one and then replace it with your modified array.

Array subproperty updates in dom-repeat is an issue that is fixed in Polymer 2 and beyond, because they removed the dirty checking.

---

Another small thing, but don't create variables inside for loops. It's a minimal time loss to create new variables inside a for loop, instead of creating one outside that you then reuse inside the loop.

```
    // Your code
  for (var j = 0; j < newItems.length; j++) {
    var item = newItems[j];
    this.setMonthAndYear(item, tempYearsArray);
  }

    // My suggestion
  var item;

  for (var j = 0; j < newItems.length; j++) {
   item = newItems[j];
   this.setMonthAndYear(item, tempYearsArray);
  }
```

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. We are in the process of updating our code from Polymer 1.x so hopefully it's not an issue going forward. And thanks for the Javascript tip. The code was actually written in Coffescript so I had to copy and strip down the compiled js code. I believe the compiled code does what you suggested, but I wanted to copy over fewer lines which is why the code isn't the most elegant.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working. It's not as elegant or perhaps as idiomatic to Polymer as possible, but it works so I'm sharing it here.

I made an `items` property which stores all the items. Then when I load a new batch of items, I push the new items to the existing items array and rebuild the entire `years` array again.